# What are the nameservers for MS Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nameservers

We have a situation in which a domain name is associated with nameservers and does not give control over DNS records.

[Windows Azure Websites documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/) explains how to work with DNS records such as `CNAME` and `A` but does not mention nameservers.

Is there a way to point a domain name at an Azure Website using `DNS1` and `DNS2` settings rather than DNS records?

Answer (score 2):

No - sorry, Azure doesn't offer Nameserver services - take a look at a solution for managed DNS like http://dyn.com/managed-dns/